# How to get the start time of a test from Pytest request fixture

Tags: pytest

As the title says, is it possible to extract the start time of a test from request fixture information.

Note I don't have direct access to Pyest.main() or its executable, meaning I can't send stuff like *--durations* or *[plugins]*.
However, I do have conftest.py if it is helping and necessary for any of suggested solutions.

Example:

```
import pytest

class TestClassSomething:
    def test_something(self):
        assert True
    
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def make_report(request) -> None:
    print(request.test_start_date)  # <--- how?
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I found a solution that sort of worked a while back, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.  Here are the conftest details:

```
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    # A column for the time of execution.
    cells.append(html.th('Time', class_='sortable time', col='time'))

def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    # A column for the time of execution.
    cells.append(html.td(datetime.utcnow(), class_='col-time'))
```

From what I can tell, it is giving me some other timestamp (maybe collection time)?  I am still occasionally searching in my spare time, though maybe this will point you  in a helpful direction.

This has been "better than nothing" for a while, but my team is increasingly looking for this information.

---

Update:  I think I found the answer here:  https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/issues/144

Instead of adding this object to each test individually, I added it to a function autouse fixture like so:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def setup_method_fixture(self):
    """Execute prior to every test method."""
    from datetime import datetime
    request.node._start_time = str(datetime.utcnow())
```

In my case, I have a test base class which all tests extend.  So putting this there allows all tests to gain access to it.  You should be able to do it without that.

This function should get run before every 'test' you collect.

From there, my conftest.py functions get updated as such:

```
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    # A column for the time of execution.
    cells.append(html.th('Time', class_='sortable time', col='time'))

def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    # A column for the time of execution.
    cells.append(html.td(report._start_time, class_='col-time'))

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
     report._start_time = getattr(item, '_start_time', 0)
```

This solves my problem.  NOTE that I am using a much older pytest, but the general theory should still work.